# Apply random value to animation-duration using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a page that generates 20 randomly sized div elements and places them in random locations within a div container.
Using CSS @keyframe animations I can apply a very simple scale and color animation to each element.

I would like to set the animation-duration CSS property to a random number for each element. I tried to do so using the jQuery.css method like so;

`element.css({ 'animation-duration': animationTime, 'animation-delay': animationTime });`

but this does not work.

Any suggestions?

The full code is below - example is live at http://codepen.io/CronanGogarty/pen/ZOexMN

```
.animationContainer {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .animationElement {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: yellow;
        animation: increase infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    @keyframes increase {
        0% {
            border-radius: 100%;
        }

        50% {
            background-color: orange;
        }

        100% {
            transform: scale(2);
            background-color: red;
        }
    }

$(function () {
        createRandomElements();
    });

    function createRandomElements() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var dimensions = Math.floor(Math.random() * (60 - 10) + 10);
            var width = $('.animationContainer').width();
            var height = $('.animationContainer').height();

            var eltop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - dimensions) + dimensions);
            var elleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - dimensions) + dimensions);

            var animationTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2;

            var element = $('<div>', {
                class: 'animationElement',
                width: dimensions,
                height: dimensions
            });
            element.css({ 'animation-duration': animationTime, 'animation-delay': animationTime });
            element.offset({ top: eltop, left: elleft });
            $('.animationContainer').prepend(element);
        }
    }
```

As an additional question - can anyone explain why the `overflow:hidden` property isn't working on the .animationContainer element? I suspect it's because the .animationElement divs are being prepended to the container - if anyone has a solution I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animation-delay` and `animation-time` need to be associated with a unit. Use the following to add an `s` (seconds) to the value. This makes the css valid.

```
element.css({
  'animation-duration': animationTime + 's',
  'animation-delay': animationTime + 's'
});
```

As a bonus, you need to set the animation-container to `position: relative` if you want its absolutely positioned children to be hidden.

[Here's a fork of your pen with the changes](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyWLYP).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `overflow:hidden` issue by adding `position:relative` to that element.